# change the uiview background color with code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, uiview

I would like to change the background color of my app programmatically, not IB. Is it possible to get both a Swift and Obj-C answer.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You can set the [`backgroundColor`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622591-backgroundcolor) property of whatever view it is you have on screen.

In Objective-C:

```c
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

In Swift:

```swift
self.view.backgroundColor = .red
```

or if it's the main window you're after,

In Objective-C:

```c
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

In Swift:

```swift
self.window.backgroundColor = .red
```

Answer (score 7):

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```

possible colors are :

```
blackColor  
 darkGrayColor  
 lightGrayColor  
 whiteColor  


 grayColor  
 redColor  
 greenColor  
 blueColor  
 cyanColor  
 yellowColor  
 magentaColor  
 orangeColor  
 purpleColor  
 brownColor  
 clearColor
```

Comment: For reference, the list of color can be currently found at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621945-clearcolor?language=objc

Answer (score 6):

For Swift 3, you should do:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

Unfortunately, the other answers no longer work in Swift 3.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the background color of the view with code in Swift, you should do instead:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor();
```

Comment: self is not necessary unless in a clousre

Answer (score 1):

You can use RGB Color by following code:

```
UIColor *myColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:(128.0 / 255.0) green:(90.0 / 255.0) 
blue:(200.0 / 255.0) alpha: 1];
self.view.backgroundcolor = mycolor;
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [answer]. You should provide some information why your code solves the problem.
Code-only answers aren't useful for the community.

Comment: Disagree with @JimHawkins - the problem with SO is not imperfect contribs like the above (which nevertheless have _some_ merit), it's dishearteningly critical comments, often of newbies.

Comment: @ColinStark - there is at least one good reason for code-only answers: the users english is too bad, but the code is helpful as it is. But code-only answers should not be a default on SO . See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/345719/1988304 . I don't see why my comment should be "dishearteningly"

Comment: First you said "code-only answers aren't useful", then said "the code is helpful as it is... should not be the default". Which is it?

 As for disheartening: well, if a newbie is trying her/his best, makes a contribution that's non-null, and immediately gets a negative "this isn't useful" aka "worthless", they may be discouraged. This has occasionally been my experience. It's also the reputation that SO has acquired.

Answer (score 1):

For swift based project you can simply type the following and press enter:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = Color Literal
```

[image]

Here the ColorLiteral property will give you a default white colour which you can change by double clicking on that colour.

You can choose from a list of colour from this popup:
[image]